# How to handle timeout using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, timeout, middleware

I want to save timeout cases by using `process_spider_exception` of `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES`.
Here are the code:

```
class CambridgespiderSpiderMiddleware(object):
    def process_spider_exception(self, response, exception, spider):
        with open(r"error_url.txt", 'a') as f:
            f.write(str(exception) + ': ' + str(response.url))  
        return response
```

setting.py is

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'CambridgeSpider.middlewares.CambridgespiderSpiderMiddleware': 543,
}
```

I use official demo to explain my trouble easily:

```
class CambridgeSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "Cambridge"
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.httpbin.org/",              # HTTP 200 expected
        "http://www.httpbin.org/status/404",    # Not found error
        "http://www.httpbin.org/status/500",    # server issue
        "http://www.httpbin.org:12345/",        # non-responding host, timeout expected
        "http://www.httphttpbinbin.org/",       # DNS error expected
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for u in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(u, callback=self.parse_httpbin,
                                    dont_filter=True)
    def parse_httpbin(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Got successful response from {}'.format(response.url))
```

The middleware was successfully loaded, but i don't know why it didn't generate the folder `error_url.txt`
Here are the logs:

```
2017-06-22 16:47:43 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.3 started (bot: CambridgeSpider)
2017-06-22 16:47:43 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'CambridgeSpider.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'Cambridge.csv', 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['CambridgeSpider.spiders'], 'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': 3, 'LOG_FILE': 'cambridge.log', 'BOT_NAME': 'CambridgeSpider', 'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 60, 'RETRY_TIMES': 3, 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True, 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2, 'AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG': True}
2017-06-22 16:47:43 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.throttle.AutoThrottle']
2017-06-22 16:47:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'CambridgeSpider.middlewares.CambridgespiderSpiderMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-06-22 16:47:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-06-22 16:47:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-06-22 16:47:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-06-22 16:47:44 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-06-22 16:47:44 [Cambridge] INFO: Spider opened: Cambridge
2017-06-22 16:47:44 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2017-06-22 16:47:44 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.httphttpbinbin.org/> (failed 1 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: www.httphttpbinbin.org.
2017-06-22 16:47:45 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: www.httpbin.org | conc: 1 | delay: 2000 ms (-1000) | latency:  644 ms | size: 12793 bytes
2017-06-22 16:47:45 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.httpbin.org/> (referer: None)
2017-06-22 16:47:45 [Cambridge] INFO: Got successful response from http://www.httpbin.org/
2017-06-22 16:47:47 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: www.httpbin.org | conc: 1 | delay: 2000 ms (+0) | latency:  321 ms | size:     0 bytes
2017-06-22 16:47:47 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://www.httpbin.org/status/404> (referer: None)
2017-06-22 16:47:47 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <404 http://www.httpbin.org/status/404>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2017-06-22 16:47:48 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.httphttpbinbin.org/> (failed 2 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: www.httphttpbinbin.org.
2017-06-22 16:47:50 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: www.httpbin.org | conc: 1 | delay: 2000 ms (+0) | latency:  316 ms | size:     0 bytes
2017-06-22 16:47:50 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.httpbin.org/status/500> (failed 1 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2017-06-22 16:47:51 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.httphttpbinbin.org/> (failed 3 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: www.httphttpbinbin.org.
2017-06-22 16:47:53 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.httphttpbinbin.org/> (failed 4 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: www.httphttpbinbin.org.
2017-06-22 16:47:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.httphttpbinbin.org/>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "j:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1299, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "j:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 393, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "j:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
  File "j:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "j:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 838, in startConnectionAttempts
    "no results for hostname lookup: {}".format(self._hostStr)
DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: www.httphttpbinbin.org.
2017-06-22 16:47:54 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: www.httpbin.org | conc: 2 | delay: 2000 ms (+0) | latency:  346 ms | size:     0 bytes
2017-06-22 16:47:54 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.httpbin.org/status/500> (failed 2 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2017-06-22 16:47:57 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: www.httpbin.org | conc: 2 | delay: 2000 ms (+0) | latency:  250 ms | size:     0 bytes
2017-06-22 16:47:57 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.httpbin.org/status/500> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2017-06-22 16:47:59 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: www.httpbin.org | conc: 2 | delay: 2000 ms (+0) | latency:  250 ms | size:     0 bytes
2017-06-22 16:47:59 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.httpbin.org/status/500> (failed 4 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2017-06-22 16:47:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (500) <GET http://www.httpbin.org/status/500> (referer: None)
2017-06-22 16:47:59 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <500 http://www.httpbin.org/status/500>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2017-06-22 16:48:11 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.httpbin.org:12345/> (failed 1 times): TCP connection timed out: 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time..
2017-06-22 16:48:29 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.httpbin.org:12345/> (failed 2 times): TCP connection timed out: 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time..
2017-06-22 16:48:44 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 3 pages (at 3 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-06-22 16:48:48 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.httpbin.org:12345/> (failed 3 times): TCP connection timed out: 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time..
2017-06-22 16:49:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.httpbin.org:12345/> (failed 4 times): TCP connection timed out: 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time..
2017-06-22 16:49:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.httpbin.org:12345/>: TCP connection timed out: 10060: \u7531\u4e8e\u8fde\u63a5\u65b9\u5728\u4e00\u6bb5\u65f6\u95f4\u540e\u6ca1\u6709\u6b63\u786e\u7b54\u590d\u6216\u8fde\u63a5\u7684\u4e3b\u673a\u6ca1\u6709\u53cd\u5e94\uff0c\u8fde\u63a5\u5c1d\u8bd5\u5931\u8d25\u3002.
2017-06-22 16:49:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-06-22 16:49:07 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 8,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError': 4,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError': 4,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 4124,
 'downloader/request_count': 14,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 14,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 14468,
 'downloader/response_count': 6,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/500': 4,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 22, 8, 49, 7, 613000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 16,
 'log_count/ERROR': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 18,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 14,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 14,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 14,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 14,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 22, 8, 47, 44, 413000)}
2017-06-22 16:49:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I know i can use

```
Request(u, callback=self.parse_httpbin,
                                    errback=self.errback_httpbin,
                                    dont_filter=True)  
def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
    if failure.check(TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError):
        with open(r"error_url.txt", 'a') as f:
            f.write(str(failure) + ': ' + str(failure.request.url))
```

to finish the same job.But my original spider use

```
rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = (r'/core/journals/ed')),)
```

it can't call the errback,so please help me.

Comment: You have defined a SpiderMiddleware class but you have included it as a downloader middleware within `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES`. Put the spider middleware in `SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES`

Comment: @paul trmbrth ,thanks for your help.It's certainly thai i confused DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES and SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES.After i defined DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES,it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a retry middleware. Make it a sub-class of the default `RetryMiddleware` instead of creating a new object. It will look like this:

```
from scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry import RetryMiddleware
from twisted.internet.error import TCPTimedOutError, TimeoutError

class FakeUserAgentErrorRetryMiddleware(RetryMiddleware):

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):   
        if isinstance(exception, TimeoutError) or isinstance(exception, TCPTimedOutError): 
            return self._retry(request, exception, spider)
```